# Issue with if else in HTML helper in cshtml file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

new to Razor/cshtml. I am facing error, that my if else is now working properly, means that the `if` is working fine but the `else` seems not working. my code shown below;

**Can someone guide me what am I doing wrong?**

```
@if (ViewBag.role == "Admin")
{
    <div id="wrapper">
<div>
some code here

}
else if (ViewBag.role == "AppAdmin")
{
<div>
some code here
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What error? And your question needs to include code, not images of it.

Comment: You are a SO veteran, you should know the rules, Add code and not the images

Comment: Sorry for the image of code. Added actual code (Edited the question)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the "else" keyword is not recognized/highlighted, i.e., the above "if" block is not well formatted. Try to exclude all above collapsed blocks (with their possible razor operations) to determine the incorrect one.